# elsif not working, continues putting if input

Tags: ruby

In my code, `elsif` does not work. If I type `"N"` or `"n"`, it will ask me for the password rather than `puts`, which it is supposed to do:

```
puts "Would you like to access Your Software Wizard?"
puts "Type Y for Yes and N for No"
answer = gets.to_s
y = "yes"
n = "no"
Y = "yes"
N = "no"
if answer == y or Y
  puts " Please Insert Password:"
  password = gets.to_s
elsif answer == n or N
  puts "Quitting..... an Alert Email and an Alert Sms has been sent to  User of attempted access"
  puts "Password has been changed and newly encripted"
  puts "Good Bye"
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several problems in your code but you've run into one of the most common, a misunderstanding of how `gets` works:

1. `answer=gets.to_s` doesn't return what you think it does. Consider this IRB session where I entered <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>Return</kbd>:

   ```
   >> gets
   1
   "1\n"
   ```

   `gets` is returning a string terminated with the "\n" which was input when <kbd>Return</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> was pressed.
2. Using `to_s` doesn't help, because `gets` is already returning a String. Like the above example, I entered `1`:

   ```
   >> gets.class
   1
   String < Object
   ```
3. Comparing the output of `gets` has to allow for the trailing "\n" somehow:

   ```
   >> gets.strip
   1
   "1"
   >> gets.chomp
   1
   "1"
   >> gets == "1\n"
   1
   true
   >> gets.chomp == '1'
   1
   true
   ```

Knowing all that, meditate on this:

```
>> answer = gets.chomp.downcase
YES
"yes"
>> answer == 'yes'
true
```

You have logic errors also, because you can't use `if answer == y or Y` or `answer == n or N`, but that's covered in https://stackoverflow.com/a/31971730/128421.

Answer (score 4):

Change `if answer == y or Y` to `if answer == y || answer == Y` or `if [y, Y].include?(answer)` (and similarly for the elsif condition).

`answer == y or Y` is testing is `answer` equal to the value of `y` OR is the value of `Y` true.  The value of `Y` will always be true as you've set it to a valid string.